# How to create a variable depth dictionary from a list or serie

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, nested, series

I need to create a function that lets me create a dictionary with the items of lists (or series) with different length. Here's how I need it to work:

```
ex=[1,2,3,4]
unknownfunction(ex)
expected output: {1:{2:{3:4}}}

    
ex2=["a","b","c","d","e"]
unknownfunction(ex2)
expected output: {"a":{"b":{"c":{"d":"e"}}}}
```

Hope you can help me with this!

Answer (score 2):

Check this recursive function

```
def func(arr):
    if len(arr) == 1:
        return arr[0]
    return {arr[0]: func(arr[1: ])}
```

Answer (score 1):

For completeness, here's an iterative solution:

```
def makenest(seq):
    dct = seq[-1]
    for s in seq[-2::-1]:
        dct = { s: dct }
    return dct


ex=[1,2,3,4]
print(makenest(ex))
#expected output: {1:{2:{3:4}}}

ex2=["a","b","c","d","e"]
print(makenest(ex2))
#expected output: {"a":{"b":{"c":{"d":{"e"}}}}}
```

Comment: [iterator version](https://tio.run/##bU7BqsIwELznK5Z4aaEXWw@PQL9EPNRm5MnjpTHZSiXk2@umgl4cmGGZ3RnWP/h3ct2PD@tqcaH/4Q8OkauIW20UCW6I1FPAHSHCbovNtyOL77BwJScv7zIFinR1JfRKfy4TRbONeVsE8BxcMZTC0h/3Tdt0zeGkfLg6rt6PYKlrtcPiMTIsTTP7mQ2lvUmtSZ055JxLQ9sf9aAbfRaOQiuE/lLXfu@TsEmSFhmL2CLQuUCt6xM) (avoids that slicing)

Answer (score 1):

Your 2 examples are a bit inconsistent (the second has the set `{"e"}` as a last element in contrast to the first one), so I am not sure what the precise specifications of this task are, but here is a solution for the first example:

```
from typing import List, Union, Dict

def unknownfunction(x: List[Union[int, float, str]]) -> Dict:
    assert len(x) >= 2, "List must have at least 2 elements"
    a = x.pop()
    b = x.pop()
    dic = {b:a}
    while x:
        c = x.pop()
        dic = {c: dic}
    return dic
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution; it is yet again another take on this problem using some built in functions and taking advantage of Python's loose structure to create something that wouldn't normally been possible or seen in many other languages.

Now, I wouldn't necessarily advocate for this approach as it could cause some confusion changing a variable type within a loop but I just thought it was a neat showcase for what you *can do* in Python. Whether it is a good idea or not.

in `stackoverflow.py`:

```py
def my_func(input: list) -> dict:
    output = input[len(input)-1]
    for index, item in enumerate(reversed(input)):
        if index == 0:
            continue

        output = {item: output}

    return output
```

In `test_stackoverflow.py`:

```py
from stackoverflow import my_func


def test_my_func_works_with_numbers():
    res = my_func([1, 2, 3, 4])
    assert res == {1: {2: {3: 4}}}


def test_my_func_works_with_strings():
    res = my_func(["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"])
    assert res == {"a": {"b": {"c": {"d": "e"}}}}


def test_my_func_works_with_combination():
    res = my_func([1, "a", 3, "b"])
    assert res == {1: {"a": {3: "b"}}}


def test_my_func_works_with_only_one_entry():
    res = my_func([1])
    assert res == 1
```